# SmartFoxServer unable to connect to server

Tags: android, smartfoxserver

I am working in android chat application.

I used SmartFox server. I am using 10.0.2.2 as server IP address and 9933 as Port.

Whenever i run this application using emulator then works fine but when i run this application in my real device then connection does not performed correctly. I think this is unable to find out IP 10.0.2.2.

I changed this IP address to 192.168.1.9 which is IP address of my system in LAN on which SmartFox server is installed.

Please suggest me what mistake i have done.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my problem myself.  I created one entry in confi/server.xml file of server.

like this:-

```
<serverSettings>
  <socketAddresses>
  <socket address="192.168.1.9" port="22" type="TCP"/>
   <socket address="192.168.1.9" port="22" type="UDP"/>
</serverSettings>
  </socketAddresses>
```

or you may add this entry using admin module of Smartfox server. This task can be done using Server configuration part.